# How would you move a UIView on screen using siri remote touchpad on tvOS

Tags: swift, uikit, tvos, uiswipegesturerecognizer, siri-remote

tvOS is so strongly built around the Focus Engine that it is unclear what one can do to move an item, let's say a simple UIView on the screen, rather than move the focus from one static object to another.

So far I've managed to create a Pan Gesture which calls a function that changes the position of the view by a certain number of points but it does not feel fluid. If you swipe on the touch pad during video scrolling the position marker slides fluidly depending on the swipe strength/distance. Is there a way to implement this on the UIView to move it across the screen in a way that matches touch on the remote touch pad?

Alternatively, would it be better or is there a possibility to move the UIView in a way that matches the finger position on the touch pad (more or less)? I know there are no absolute coordinates on the touch pad but perhaps this can be approximate. It would be a cursor like effect although not actually creating a cursor as a pointing mechanism (which I know is not allowed on tvOS).

Thanks in advance.